# How do I title within a string?

Tags: python

I just started doing Python and came across an issue I hope more experienced Python users can help me out with.

```
place=input("Enter a place: ")

print(place.title())

print("The poster announced that a pet show is held at," place, ".")
```

Issue I have is when I run it, when the user first inputs a place and types in los angeles, Python capitalizes the first word of every letter because of title.  When I run the second string though, the place wouldn't be capitalized properly.  So in this case, it will show up as los angeles.  How do I fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: In Python strings are immutable. Therefore when you call string methods you'll get back a new string, every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, you are printing the original, un-titled variable.

Print it titled again.

```
print("The poster announced that a pet show is held at {}.".format(place.title()))
```

Or save the titled string.

```
place=input("Enter a place: ").title()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the output from `place.title()` into a variable.  Something like this:

```
proper_caps_place = place.title()
```

Then use your new variable in your last print statement, which you'll need to change to use string concatenation.  Try this:

```
print("The poster announced that a pet show is held at, " + proper_caps_place + ".")
```